# Should I remove ICMP Protocol from firewall rules base on security concern?

Tags: centos, security, firewall, icmp

[image: Server firewall rules from Google Cloud Platform]

As you can see from the screenshot of GCP firewall rule page, should I remove ICMP Protocol from firewall rules base on security concern? Will it lower the chance of being attacked?

I'm using CentOS 7. I added `net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1` to `/etc/sysctl.d`. Does this have the same effect as deleting the ICMP Protocol from GCP firewall rules page?

Comment: See also [Security risk of PING?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/security-risk-of-ping)

Comment: @Sjoerd I checked the link. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you can see from the screenshot of GCP firewall rule page, should I remove ICMP Protocol from firewall rules base on security concern? Will it lower the chance of being attacked?

Opinions differ about this, but it is generally not considered a security risk to accept ICMP packets.

> I'm using CentOS 7. I added net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1 to /etc/sysctl.d. Does this have the same effect as deleting the ICMP Protocol from GCP firewall rules page?

No. There are several types of ICMP requests. Ping or echo requests are just one of them. The setting `icmp_echo_ignore_all` only disables ping responses, while blocking ICMP in the firewall will block all ICMP traffic, ping and all others. This will cause problems, as ICMP packets are sometimes necessary for proper operation.

Comment: Thanks again! @Sjoerd

Answer (score 1):

There's been many discussions around ICMP allowing leaking type of messages. However, it was strengthen in ICMPv6 which would mean that all the CVE about those messages are probably obsolete (see [CVE about ping](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-1999-0523) and [CVE about timestamp](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-1999-0524)).

The ping utility gives information about your system. Mainly that it is up. If you have any other service, say a website, the hacker knows your system is up anyway.

The timestamp returns the current time of your computer. This is viewed as a bad one because many systems used the current time to generate random numbers. I think most such systems are not facing the client accessible services (i.e. I still use `time_t now = time(nullptr); srand(now);` in my unit tests, where it is perfectly safe).

Again, trying to hide the timestamp by blocking that ICMP message is not likely going to be helpful. When you access a webpage on the same server you get a `Date: ...` field with the current time. With enough hits you can determine a very close approximation of the date and time of any webserver.

For those interested, here are rules to block the ping & timestamp:

```
-A INPUT --ipv4 -i eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
-A INPUT --ipv4 -i eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type timestamp-request -j DROP
```

and as mentioned above, you probably do not want to use them. The ping is actually useful for you to test that your system works and blocking it is just not the best idea.

To get a complete list of the supported ICMP types use:

```
$ iptables -p icmp -h
$ ip6tables -p icmpv6 -h
```